# Will a current flow in a split circuit with moving parts?

Tags: special-relativity, electricity

Say a half of the circuit is moving with high speed relative to the other half, so that they undergo a significant contraction. Will there appear a current when they pass each other?

Stationary situation:

```
A       B
---( )---
|       |
|       |
---( )---
```

The source and bulbs (or other elements) are not included in the schema for simplicity. Let's assume the circuit is closed when the circuit is stationary and there is a current. The `(` and `)` symbolise connectors of some length, so that each pair next to one another establishes a connection of the two halves.

The motion is such, that the contraction affects the distance between both pluses of the same half.

In the stationary frame of B, the A's movement looks like this:

```
        B
     +---
        |
        |
     +---

A
---+   ^
|      | (this is supposed to be the velocity vector)
---+
```

Will the connectors meat? Will there be a current?

Comment: You may be interested in this video from Veritasium - [How Special Relativity Makes Magnets Work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TKSfAkWWN0). And this one that clarifies some confusing points - [Veritasium's 'How Special Relativity Makes Magnets Work' - EXPLAINED](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWiY5kVw9U4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in the Barn Door paradox.

Here are some important points regarding your setup:

1. The "Stationary Setup" seems to show that both halves are moving at the same speed, while the "Moving Setup" shows one half moving and the other not. These are not compatible.  In the 2nd setup, if B is moving from A's point of view, then A is moving from B's point of view. There is no observer who sees both as stationary.
2. Circuit theory is a simplistic approximation that allows us to design electrical systems in most real life situations, but it is not valid for situations with transient behavior, such is the few microseconds after you flip on a light switch and the electric fields are spreading through the system. And it certainly is not valid when things are moving at relativistic speeds.  I invite you to check out some of the animations in [this video](https://youtu.be/oI_X2cMHNe0?t=615),  especially the ones made by Ben Watson which model exactly what the fields are doing per Maxwell's Equations.

Comment: Thanks. Your point 1 is obvious to me. I will be thinking through the Maxwell's in the future.